# Google Sheets App Script Goal: Timestamp todays date in next empty column cell whenever checkbox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google Sheet to record each day a certain activity is done (watering plants). I have written a script so that when the checkbox in each row is checked (TRUE), todays date is timestamped into the adjacent column cell. But I can't figure out how to timestamp a new "todays date" into the next empty cell in the same row each time I activate the checkbox. I'd like to keep adding new dates the activity is performed into the adjacent empty cells in the same row. (ultimately I want to then average the number of days between each date so I can collect data and average the number of days between waterings for each plant - which is a different formula challenge). The working script I have created is:

```
   function onEdit(e){
  if(e.value != "TRUE") return;
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart + 1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the sheet and what I would like to achieve:
[Screenshot visualisation of what I want the script to be able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRQzF.png)

Much appreciated if anyone could help me out with a working code. Thanks!

Comment: do you only want timestamp each time the checkbox is enabled (on), or do you want the timestamp every time the checkbox is enabled (on) AND disabled (off)?

Comment: Hi, I'd like the time stamp only when checkbox is turned on. When it is turned off, nothing should happen. The checkbox is performing like a button to create a timestamp.

Comment: Without a script! https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494266/14915635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.value != "TRUE") return;
  var cel = e.source.getActiveRange()
  if (cel.offset(0,1).getValue()!=""){cel = e.source.getActiveRange().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT)}
  cel.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

edit : to drag all the dates (with optional uncheck)

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.value != "TRUE") return;
  var cel = e.source.getActiveRange()
  if (cel.offset(0,1).getValue()!=""){
    var area = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(cel.getRow(),cel.getColumn()+1,1,cel.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn()-cel.getColumn())
    area.copyTo(area.offset(0,1),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  }
  cel.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  // optional:
  cel.setValue(!cel.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mike - This worked! Now that I am playing with it, I am wondering if there is a script to create a new empty column adjacent to the checkbox after the timestamp is entered? It would be better to always keep the latest date entry next to the checkbox column, while older dates get pushed farther out. Is this possible?

Comment: ok, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Your sheet name' && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, it seems to work for the first TRUE instance of the checkbox, but for subsequent TRUE instances it does not enter a timestamp in new columns.

Comment: hmm, not sure why it is not working for me then. the code above is everything i need to have in the script? (I have changed the sheet name to the name of my sheet). It does enter a timestamp in the adjacent row... but if I turn off and on the same checkbox, timestamps do not continue to populate in new columns across the same row.